# Replacing value between 2 characters

Tags: python, regex

```
url="https://ensia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-167x378.jpg"
```

I have this url ans i am trying to replace the `167 * 378` with `920*458`. This is basically the dimensions of image. I tried this code:

```
url.replace("/-.*./","920x458")
```

but nothing is changing in url. What I want in output is:

```
"https://ensia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-950x458.jpg"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Match `-\d+x\d+` and replace with -920x458

Comment: print(re.sub(r"(\d+)x(\d+)","920x458", url))

Comment: You might also want to edit the question because you said 920*458 before, and in the expected output, there is 950x458.

Answer (score 1):

my opinion is, that string replacement is more readable and obviouse, also easier to debug in case of failure. And it is faster in most cases then regexp !

```
def change_url_resolution(url: str, x: int, y: int) -> str: 
    """
    Changes the resolution in the url 
    >>> url="https://ensia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-167x378.jpg"
    >>> change_url_resolution(url, 920, 458)
    'https://ensia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-920x458.jpg'
    """
    # we only need the part left of the rightmost '-'
    url_prefix = url.rsplit('-',1)[0]
    # all the rest we can construct ourself
    result = ''.join([url_prefix, '-', str(x), 'x', str(y), '.jpg'])
    # or if You like it better (from python 3.6) : 
    result = f"{url_prefix}-{x}x{y}.jpg"
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try following regex:

```
(?<=-)\d+x\d+
```

Details:

- `(?<=-)`: you get only text after character hyphen
- `\d+x\d+`: you get current image size

I have tried running on Python

```
import re

url = "https://ensia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-167x378.jpg"

print("url before replacing")
print(url)
url = re.sub(r"(?<=-)\d+x\d+", "920x458", url)
print("url after replacing")
print(url)
```

Result what I get:

```
url before replacing
https://ensia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-167x378.jpg
url after replacing
https://ensia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-920x458.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [string.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), you can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and match the hyphen and the dimension where `\d+` matches one or more digits:

```
-\d+x\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdUh3W/1)

And replace with `-920x458`

---

If the dimensions should end with *.jpg* you could use a positive lookahead `(?=\.jpg$)` to assert that it follows directly after the dimensions till the end of the string.

If `.jpg` should be a broader match, you can also match 1 or more word characters using `\.\w+` instead.

```
-\d+x\d+(?=\.jpg$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7B8RnD/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/J7Kvso)

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"-\d+x\d+(?=\.jpg$)"
url="https://e...content-available-to-author-only...a.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-167x378.jpg"
print(re.sub(regex, "-920x458", url))
```

*Output*

```
https://ensia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-920x458.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Python's default `re` module:

```
import re
url = 'https://ensia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/abc_def_ghi-167x378.jpg'
new_url = re.sub('[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}', '950x458', url)
```

- `[0-9]` matches any digit from 0 to 9.
- `[0-9]{3}` means any digits from 0 to 9 appearing 3 times (e.g. 123).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
re.sub(r'(?<=-)\d+x\d+(?=\.[^.]*$)', r'920x458', url)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/JMpzbX/1). It will only `re.sub` the numbers at the end of the file name  right before the file extension.

**EXPLANATION**

```
                        EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  x                        'x'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.]*                    any character except: '.' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```